# Using php7 and curl to create job in jenkins via api

Tags: xml, curl, jenkins, binary, php-7

I'm trying to create job in jenkins using rest api and php7
95% sure that I need request like this

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://jenkins/job/FolderName/createItem?name=yourJobName' --data-binary @config.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml" --user user.name:YourAPIToken
```

But I always get errors like "Failed to persist config.xml" and "Content is not allowed in prolog". My guess is that the problem appears because I don't use the --data-binary param
I just cannot figure out how to do it in php 7 where we use "new CurlFile
For understanding, here is my code:

```
$url = static::$host.'/job/'.$folderName.'/createItem?name='.$jobname;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Array('file' => new CurlFile($xmlConfigurationFile)));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, static::$user.":".static::$pass);
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/xml');
if ($jenkins->areCrumbsEnabled()){
    $headers[] = $jenkins->getCrumbHeader();
}
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

In $xmlConfigurationFile is path to file
Also there is no problem with auth, csrf, folder creation or file path

So the question is:
How can I send xml file in binary via curl in php7?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you thought about using a PHP library for Jenkins? There seem to be a couple of them on [packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=jenkins).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it
I don't understand the logic, but it works for me
I've changed this

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, Array('file' => new CurlFile($xmlConfigurationFile)));
```

Where $xmlConfigurationFile is path to file. To this

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlConfiguration);
```

Where $xmlConfiguration is content of file
And job has been created

it will be cool if someone post explanation, however problem is solved